# How can I select all Eloquent models from a MySQL database inserted today, within the last week or the last month?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-4

I have an Eloquent Model (`Test`) associated with a MySQL table called `tests`, with the following structure:

```
tests
id          int
created_at  date
updated_at  date
correct     boolean
```

I am trying to select only those tests created today, within the last 7 days and within the last month, something like this (**pseudocode**):

```
$todays_tests = Test::where('created_at','=', 'today');
$this_weeks_tests = Test::where('created_at','=', 'last 7 days');
$this_months_tests = Test::where('created_at','=', 'last month');
```

I'm sure Laravel provides an easy way to do this but I'm not sure how best to go about it. Presumably I need to use a raw MySQL query?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure you can do some nice things with the `Carbon` plugin. The Carbon documentation: https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

For example for created today, if you add this in your Test model:

```
public function scopeCreatedToday($query)
{
    return $query->whereBetween('created_at', array(Carbon::today(), Carbon::today()->addDay()));
}
```

You will be able to do: `$tests = Test::createdToday()->get();`.